# Publish item as other user with Core Service

Tags: core-service

I have a GUI Extension calling the core service to publish a page.  However, the publish user is always the impersonation user.  I want the publish user to be the one using the GUI.     I have the following code, but it only works when I add an impersonation user, and the actions are then performed by the impersonation user:

```
string binding = "netTcp_2011";

using (var client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(binding))
{
    client.Impersonate("robert");  
    //....
    client.Publish(arrItems, instruction, target.ToArray(), GetPublishPriority(publishItem.Priority), readoptions);
}
```

Is there any way to execute the client.Publish command under the identity of the GUI user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because your code is executed by the Application Pool user (defaults to `Network Service`) which is not allowed to use Tridion - for a very good reason.

You can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to get the current user.

```
client.Impersonate(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

PS - This will work for Windows and LDAP or SSO users too.